# Does move semantic unsuitable to the array in C++11?

Tags: arrays, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I test the unique_ptr<> as follow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void print()
    {
            cout << "A::Print()" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
    virtual void print()
    {
            cout << "B::Print()" << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    A* arr[2] = {&a, &b};
    arr[0]->print();
    arr[1]->print();

    unique_ptr<A*[]> ptr(move(arr));
    /*
    unique_ptr<A*[]> ptr(new A*[2]{&a, &b});
    */
    ptr[0]->print();
    ptr[1]->print();

    return 0;
}
```

It get the result like (g++ 4.7.3)

```
A::Print()
B::Print()
A::Print()
B::Print()
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It seem like the `ptr` and `arr` point to the samething and when call
destructor, it has been deleted twice.

Why the move semantic don't take effect here?

Does it unsuitable to the array or it is about the unique_ptr?

Comment: The other guy at least deserves an UV, he technically answered first :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you have no dynamically allocated memory here (never use the new keyword). So the unique_ptr is trying to free memory (call delete on) that was never allocated. My suggestion try to write simpler code, because you do a ton of things that are very unconventional.

1. You store `A*` for no reason, they will be delete automatically, I can't think of any good reason to store them as pointers
2. You don't use any standard library containers, you could use a  `std::array<A,2>` instead of a c-style array
3. Also I'm guessing you just made this as a test so I can't really tell what your trying to achieve here

Comment: @CLS things tend to work better and look nicer when you use the STL

Comment: I don't know what you mean...I just read the STL and has a test on the unique_ptr, so fool that I forget that `delete` an object which was not allocate with `new` is undefined behavior, I mistakenly think it may the problem with move semantic

Comment: @CLS happens to everyone sometimes ;)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that `unique_ptr<T>` assumes that the object it manages was allocated with `new`. Since it is statically allocated on the stack instead, the `unique_ptr` destructor crashes when it tries to `delete` your array.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this `unique_ptr` anyways. Unique pointers make sure that the managed object is deleted at the end of the scope, but arrays allocated on the stack *are* deleted at the end of the scope, inherently. Would you have no `unique_ptr`, your code would function the same and not leak anyways.